# minifyEnabled:true in release app crash support v4

Tags: android, gradle, proguard, minify

when i add the `minifyEnable:true` in the build.gradle file under the release buildType, the app crash with this log:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.getCurrentItem()' on a null object reference
   at com.myapp.springindicator.SpringIndicator.createPoints(Unknown Source)
   at com.myapp.springindicator.SpringIndicator.onLayout(Unknown Source)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1735)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1579)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1488)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1735)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1579)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1488)
   ...
```

Someone can help me? i've already added this in the proguard file:

`-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
 -keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
 -keep class android.support.v7.app.** { *; }
 -keep interface android.support.v7.app.** { *; }`

I also tried with keep app classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-keep class android.support.** { *; }` worked well for me.

Try out that, because you are just keeping the classes under  `android.support.v4.app.` only, and crashing at `android.support.v4.view.`

Comment: Happy to hear. Accepting answer would be worthy too! =D